Resizing of Lottie in swiftUI
Is there any way to expand my lottie animation to a given frame.
I am currently using below modifiers, I am getting the correct height and width but my lottie is not filling that, only covering the height.
LottieView {
    try await DotLottieFile.named("animationFileName")
}
.playing()
.resizable()
.animationSpeed(0.4)
.animationDidFinish { _ in
    isExpanded = false
}
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
.clipShape(.rect(cornerRadius: 24))
.frame(maxWidth: isPlaying ? .infinity : selectedFireFrame.width,
       maxHeight: isPlaying ? .infinity : selectedFireFrame.height)
.position(x: isPlaying ? UIScreen.main.bounds.midX : selectedFireFrame.midX,
          y: isPlaying ? UIScreen.main.bounds.midY : selectedFireFrame.midY)
.onAppear {
    // Delay before starting the expansion
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { // some delay
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
            isPlaying = true
        }
    }
}

I used .resizable() modifier and set the frame too.
